# Checkbox fica bugado MARCAR TODOS -RETIRAR SELEÇÃO -Caso especial;

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

Olá pessoal meu objetivo é marcar e desmarcar os checkboxs até aí tudo certo olhem na print:
[image: OLHEM ALI NO SELECIONAR TODOS E RETIRAR SELEÇÃO]

Eu aperto pra selecionar todos e  o script seleciona TODOS eu clico pra desmarcar ele desmarca TODOS ate ai tudo certo.

O PROBLEMA é que se eu for com a setinha do mouse e clicar num checkbox daqueles e retirar a seleção e depois clicar em selecionar todos eles NÃO SÃO SELECIONADOS PELA FERRAMENTA SELECIONAR TODOS QUE EU CRIEI.
Entendem?

Tipo assim:

1- Eu cliquei em selecionar todos, agora ta todo mundo selecionado como na imagem.

2-Eu escolho a primeira checkbox e desmarco.

3-Agora eu vou clicar em selecionar todos.

4-O selecionar todos não marca minha 1 checkbox. 
Entende agr?

meu script é esse:

```
//AQUI É PRA SELECIONAR TODOS OS CHECKBOX AMIGOS O BOTÃO AZUL LA ENCIMA SELECIONAR TODOS
$('.selecionadinho').bind('click',function() {

            $('.checkboxs').each( function() {

                $(this).attr('checked',true);

            }
            );  

    });


//AQUI ESSE CODIGO VAI RETIRAR TODOS OS CHECKBOX AZUL LA ENCIMA RETIRAR SELEÇÃO DE TODOS
        $('.retirar').bind('click',function() {

            $('.checkboxs').each( function() {

                $(this).attr('checked',false);

            }
            );  

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Duas coisas a consertar no seu código:

**1.** Troque `.bind` por `.on`, porque `.bind()` não se usa mais, foi descontinuado no jQuery 3.0.

```
$('.selecionadinho').on('click',function() {...
$('.retirar').on('click',function() {...
```

**2.** Não use `.attr` para alterar valor booleano *true* e *false* de `input`. Use `.prop`:

```
$(this).prop('checked',false); ou $(this).prop('checked',true);
```

Com essas alterações seu código irá funcionar redondo.

### SUGESTÃO para melhorar o código:

Em vez de usar duas funções para isso, você pode usar apenas uma:

Coloque nos links "SELECIONAR TODOS" e "RETIRAR SELEÇÃO DE TODOS" a mesma `class="sel_tudo_nada"`, e substitua as suas duas funções por apenas esta:

```
$('.sel_tudo_nada').on('click',function(){
   var checar = $(this).index() == 0 ? true : false;
   $('.checkboxs').each( function() {
      $(this).prop('checked',checar);
   });
});
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

O código:

```
var checar = $(this).index() == 0 ? true : false;
```

é uma forma abreviada de:

```
// $(this).index() é o índice do link clicado,
// onde 0 é o primeiro e 1 seria o segundo
if( $(this).index() == 0 ){
   checar = true;
}else{
   checar = false;
}
```

Comment: Valeu! Agora a sugestão de melhoramento sua não aceito pra ninguém poucas pessoas iriam entender isso aí , muito menos eu, não entendi nada dessa parte $(this).index() == 0 ? true : false;

Comment: Um código pequeno difícil custa muito mais do que um grandão amigo, mas VOCe me ajudou mt to desde ontem sem saber o q fazer.

Comment: valeuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: @ProgramadorInteligente Coloquei uma atualização na resposta que explica o lance do código que vc não entendeu. Abs!

Comment: @ProgramadorInteligente Se a resposta foi útil e ajudou, por favor marque ✔